# Show file information that is transferring using Django celery?

Tags: django, django-celery

I have a task like this in Django celery:

```
@task
def file(password, source12, destination):
    subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '-avz', '--info=progress2', source12, destination], 
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

I have a function that executes the above task:

```
@celery.task
@login_required(login_url='/login_backend/') 
def sync(request):
    #user_id = request.session['user_id']
    """Sync the files into the server with the progress bar"""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        choices = request.POST.getlist('choice') 
        for i in choices:
            new_source = source +"/"+ i 
            #b = result.successful()
            #result.get() #Poll the database to get the progress
            start_date1 = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
            source12 = new_source.replace(' ', '') #Remove whitespaces
            file.delay(password, source12, destination)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/uploaded_files/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/uploaded_files/')
```

I want to show the user the file transferring information with the progress.I want to show the `file name, remaining time and size of the file` that is being transferred. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have [example](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states) of how pass the information through celery itself. Simply start upload process as an AJAX call, return task`s id and later ask by AJAX about state of the task.

To actually know how you're doing you need to know the progress in the `file` task itself. I doubt if you can achieve that by calling subprocess `sshpass` in other way then parsing `PIPE` output.

Mind celery spawn a process for you already when you `.delay` a task.

Try to read destination in chunks, rsync the chunks and then merge the file in destination. That way you know how many chunks you've transferred already.